# Why are these unbounded operators (essentially) self-adjoint?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian

Can anyone provide exact mathematical reasoning as to why the following fundamental unbounded symmetric operators are **essentially self-adjoint**? I.e. on, their natural domains,  they admit a unique selfadjoint extension.

I know that the position and momentum operators $\hat{X}$  and $\hat{P}$ are self-adjoint on their domain. I also know that it is not true that the sum of self-adjoint unbounded operators is self-adjoint.

$\bullet$ The number operator acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$: $\hat{N}:= A^\dagger A.$

$\bullet$ Hamiltonian for the displacement operator acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$: $$\hat{H}(\alpha)={\alpha A^{\dagger}-\alpha^* A},$$ for a complex number $\alpha.$

$\bullet$ For $\zeta \in \mathbb{R},$ the hamiltonian of squeezing operator acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$
$$
\hat{H}_S = i\frac{\zeta}{2}\left(\hat{A}^2-\hat{A}^{\dagger 2}\right). 
$$

$\bullet$ For $\zeta \in \mathbb{R},$ the hamiltonian for two-mode squeezing operator acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ by
$$
\hat{H}_{S_2} = i\frac{\zeta}{2}\left(\hat{A_1}\hat{A_2}-\hat{A_1}^{\dagger}\hat{A_2}^{\dagger }\right). 
$$

$\bullet$ For $\zeta \in \mathbb{R},$ the hamiltonian of the beam-splitter operator acting on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ by
$$
\hat{H}_{BS} = i\frac{\zeta}{2}\left(\hat{A_1}^{\dagger}\hat{A_2}-\hat{A_1}\hat{A_2}^{\dagger }\right). 
$$

Comment: The maximal common dense domain in $L^2$ (for example Schwartz space) is a domain of essential self-adjointness. Plus the chosen domain must ensure invariance (i.e. operator functions need to be defined). Which is all we need.

Answer (score 1):

A generally good idea is to consider the Schwartz space
$$\mathcal S(\mathbb R) := \{f \in L^2(\mathbb R) \ |  \ \forall n,m\in \mathbb N : x^n f^{(m)} \in L^2(\mathbb R) \}$$
where $f^{(m)}$ is the $m^{th}$ derivative of $f$.  On this domain, a great many operators of interest can be shown to be essentially self-adjoint.

Consider the restriction of $H=a^\dagger a$ to this domain. Ignoring constant factors, this operator is equal to $\frac{1}{2}(P^2 + X^2)$, where I have used the fact that $P$ and $X$ are essentially self-adjoint on this domain as well.   We can prove the essential self-adjointness by computing the deficiency indices
$$d_{\pm} = \mathrm{dim}\big( \mathrm{ker}(H^\dagger  \mp i) \big)$$

To do this, we must first computer $H^\dagger$.  To be explicit, we take the domain of $H$ to be $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$. The domain of $H^\dagger$ is the set of all $\psi \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ for which there exists some $\eta_\psi \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ such that, for all $\phi \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R)$,
$$\langle \psi, H\phi \rangle = \langle \eta_\psi,\phi\rangle$$
From there, we define $\eta_\psi = : H^\dagger \psi.$ In our case,

$$\langle \psi, H\phi\rangle = \int \mathrm dx \ \overline{\psi(x)} \big(-\frac{1}{2}\phi''(x) + \frac{1}{2} x^2 \phi(x) \big)$$
We may integrate by parts twice iff $\psi$ is twice weakly-differentiable, in which case we obtain

$$\langle \psi,H\phi\rangle = \int \mathrm dx \ \left(\overline{-\frac{1}{2}\psi''(x) + \frac{1}{2}x^2 \psi(x) }\right) \phi(x)  \equiv \langle \eta_\psi, \phi\rangle$$
where
$$\eta_\psi(x)\equiv \big(H^\dagger \psi\big)(x) = -\frac{1}{2} \psi''(x) + \frac{1}{2}x^2 \psi(x)$$

Therefore, we find that $H^\dagger$ is the operator whose domain is all twice weakly-differentiable elements $\psi\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ such that
$$-\frac{1}{2}\psi'' + \frac{1}{2}x^2 \psi$$
is also an element of $L^2(\mathbb R)$, and its action on such functions is given by the above formula (note that this space is, as expected, strictly larger than $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$).

---

Now that we know what $H^\dagger$ is, we can compute the deficiency indices.

$$\mathrm{ker}(H^\dagger \mp i)  = \{f \in \mathrm{dom}(H^\dagger) \ | \ H^\dagger f = \pm i f\}$$

In our case, this corresponds to solutions of
$$f''(x) -(x^2 \pm 2i) f(x) = 0$$
which lie in the domain of $H^\dagger$.  Being a second order linear differential equation, the dimensionality of the solution space of this equation is $2$ - however, the dimensionality of the solution space of this equation *which lies in the domain of $H^\dagger$* is zero, since [none of the solutions are square-integrable](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%27%27%28x%29+-+%28x%5E2+-+2i%29+f%28x%29+%3D+0) (except $f = 0$, of course).

Since this holds for both signs of $i$, it follows that both deficiency indices $d_+$ and $d_-$ are zero. [This indicates that $H$ is essentially self-adjoint](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/534226/essential-self-adjointness/577049#577049), as requested. More or less the same approach can be used for any operator on any domain to decide the question of essential self-adjointness, with varying degrees of ease.

Answer (score 0):

Let me expand on my comment:

For every operator you mentioned, I assume that $A$ is a certain function of $X$ and $P$ and possibly their powers with their usual definitions in $L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ which come from the Stone - von Neumann uniqueness theorem.

The first thing to know is that if there's a domain $D(A)$ for which an operator $A$ is self-adjoint, this is maximal, i.e. there's no proper superset of $D(A)$ in the Hilbert space which respects the self-adjointness condition in terms of the scalar product. For this reason, von Neumann called self-adjoint operators *hyper-maximal symmetric*.

The second thing to know is that the domain of self-adjointness of $A$ is not the domain of self-ajointness of an arbitrary function $A$ such as a power. This is easy to see in the simplest case:

$$ D(A^2) := \{\psi\in D(A)| A\psi \in D(A) \} \subsetneq D(A) $$

Because of this, we usually search for what we call *common dense everywhere invariant domains* of our operators. If the assume that the physical dynamics is infinite, i.e. the Hilbert space is $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then  [the space of Schwartz test functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) furnishes everything we need: $X,P$ and any functions of $X,P$ (in particular $A$, its adjoint, their sum, their product) are essentially self-adjoint operators so that for any operator defined there is a single self-adjoint proper extension.

So even if we say "an observable must be represented by a self-adjoint operator", then all the operators we want to use and call observables are the unique extensions of the original operators defined on $\mathcal{S}$.

So go back to the definition of each operator you propose and see, for example, that if you manage to have/find a domain of self-adjointness for $A$, then $ N = A^{\dagger}A = A^2 $ cannot be self-adjoint on the same domain. So we "relax" the condition for $A$, i.e. restrict it to an invariant essential self-adjointness domain such as the Schwartz space, then $N$ will be essential self-adjoint on the same domain.

The advantage of having only e.s.a. operators comes from a very interesting thing:

If $A$ is self-adjoint on its maximal domain $D(A)$, then the rigged Hilbert space $\Phi \subset \mathcal{H} \subset \Phi^{\times}$ fully solving its spectral equation has $\Phi$ as an essential self-adjointness domain (which in turn is endowed with a stronger topology generated by a family of semi-norms). You can check that for the free particle, Hydrogen atom, harmonic oscillator, etc.

Comment: What I really wanted is the mathematical details (or a reference).